# Getting JavaScript to display div based on text field

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have been working on this JavaScript file so that as someone types in more text, they will see a different div showing them a piece of code (soon to be a Paypal button).

For some reason, I cannot get the divs to show up.  I have used both `onchange` and `onkeyup` and neither seem to be helping.  So, here is the code:

```
<br/>Word Count: <input type="text" id="c" name="c" value="311" size="5"
onkeyup="cnt(document.script.w,this)" onchange="showDiv()"/>
</form>

<div id="div1" style="display:none">
Price level 1!
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display:none">
Price level 2!
</div>

<div id="div3" style="display:none">
Price level 3!
</div>

<div id="div4" style="display:none">
Price level 4!
</div>

<div id="div5" style="display:none">
Price level 5!
</div>

<div id="div6" style="display:none">
Price level 6!
</div>

<div id="div7" style="display:none">
Price level 7!
</div>
```

Script

```
function showDiv() {
    var myNumValue = document.getElementById('c').value;
    var myNum = parseInt(myNumValue);
    var price1=0;
    var price2=100;
    var price3=200;
    var price4=300;
    var price5=400;
    var price6=500;
    var price7=600;
    
    if (myNum >= price1 && myNum <= price2) {
        document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
    }
    elseif(myNum >= price2 && myNum <= price3) {
        document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
    }
    elseif(myNum >= price3 && myNum <= price4) {
        document.getElementById('div3').style.display = 'block';
    }
    elseif(myNum >= price4 && myNum <= price5) {
        document.getElementById('div4').style.display = 'block';
    }
    elseif(myNum >= price5 && myNum <= price6) {
        document.getElementById('div5').style.display = 'block';
    }
    elseif(myNum >= price6 && myNum <= price7) {
        document.getElementById('div6').style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('div7').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

So, any ideas on how to get this to work?  I know I am probably just missing something simple, just need a couple of extra pairs of eyes.

Comment: I added a `<br/>` to the start of the code, purely so that the code formatter would recognize your code as HTML.  It shouldn't make a difference to any potential answers.

Comment: By the way, you might want to get rid of those braces in that if/else... for readability (or just put the first `{` on the same line as the `if(...)`, like you did for `function showDiv() {`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `elseif` => `else if` issue that amurra points out is your general problem, but I'd also like to suggest an alternative approach that uses an array of element IDs rather than `if`s and `else if`s.  For instance:

```
function showDiv() {
    var myNumValue = document.getElementById('c').value,
        myNum = Math.min(Math.floor(parseInt(myNumValue, 10) / 100), 6),
        myDiv = ["div1", "div2", "div3", "div4", "div5", "div6", "div7"][myNum];

    document.getElementById(myDiv).style.display = "block";
}
```

Much tidier, right? Live example at: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/FFeLC/1/ :-)

Note, however, that it's not quite the same.  In your example, if the value were 300 then div3 would be shown.  In my example, div4 would be shown (which I think is more likely what you need).  If you would prefer it how you have it in your code, you can subtract any amount between 0 and 0.1 from `myNumValue` after parsing it (and before dividing by 100) to get the same result you would expect from your code.

Also, this is probably what you really want: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/FFeLC/2/.

Answer (score 2):

A space between the `elseif` might help `elseif` => `else if`

Comment: Duh! See I told you it must have been something simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having multiple divs you could just alter the content of one specific div based on input. Something like..

```
<br/>Word Count: <input type="text" id="c" name="c" value="311" size="5"
onkeyup="showDiv()" onchange="showDiv()"/>
</form>

<div id="priceInfo">
    Enter Price
</div>
```

JS

```
function showDiv() {

    var myNumValue = document.getElementById('c').value,
        myNum = parseInt(myNumValue),
        priceFound = false;
    var priceBank = {
        'Price Level 1!': 0,
        'Price Level 2!': 100,
        'Price Level 3!': 200,
        'Price Level 4!': 300,
        'Price Level 5!': 400,
        'Price Level 6!': 500,
        'Price Level 7!': 600
    }

    for (var price in priceBank) {
        if ( myNum <= priceBank[price]) {
            document.getElementById('priceInfo').innerHTML = price;
            priceFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( !priceFound ) {
        document.getElementById('priceInfo').innerHTML = 'no price level found for this amount.';
    }
}
```

Example here: [JSBin.com](http://jsbin.com/inexi5/edit)​